# Declaration for Module Exporting Object

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

I have a project that compiles and exposes two CommonJS modules; each of them an object. Then, I have another project that consumes them.

The project structures are as follows:

```
multi-mod-package
|-mod1
| |-index.js
|-mod2
| |-index.js
|-package.json
multi-mod-consumer
|-index.ts
|-package.json
|-tsconfig.json
```

And the file contents:

**multi-mod-package/mod1/index.js**

```
module.exports.default = {
    "count": "One"
};
```

**multi-mod-package/mod2/index.js**

```
module.exports.default = {
    "count": "Two"
};
```

**multi-mod-consumer/index.ts**

```
import one  from "multi-mod-package/mod1";
import two  from "multi-mod-package/mod2";

console.log(`${one.count}, ${two.count}, Buckle My Shoes`);
```

**multi-mod-consumer/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "include": [
        "index.ts"
    ]
}
```

Without the `noImplicitAny`, this works fine. The project compiles, and `One, Two, Buckle My Shoes` is output as expected. However, the modules have no typings. I would like to enable `noImplicitAny` and have proper typings for these modules, so I am trying to write declaration files for each. I have tried a number of iterations of `declare module` and `declare namespace`, but I keep getting "... is not a module" errors when attempting to consume the modules.

How do I write a declaration file for a module that exports an object?

**UPDATE**

Adding two definition files - `multi-mod-package/mod1/index.d.ts` and `multi-mod-package/mod1/index.d.ts` - with the contents `declare module "multi-mod-package/mod1";` and `declare module "multi-mod-package/mod1";` - respectively - gets rid of the "... is not a module" errors. However, there is still no proper typings; `one.count` still comes up as type `any`.

When I try to give the module a body (even just an empty one), TypeScript complains that the module has no default export. So, I still need a solution for telling TypeScript the module is an object containing the `count` property.

Comment: You need to provide an example. And what does it mean by exposing two CommonJS modules? You only have one "main" field in package.json.

Comment: @unional I added a basic code example. There is no `main` field; the modules are intended to be consumed as shown in the example.

Comment: try `declare module 'multi-mod-packages/mod1'` and `.../mod2'` directly.

Comment: Adding `declare module "multi-mod-package/mod1";` helps TypeScript recognize the file as a module which is a huge step in the right direction. The original issue still stands though: now I need to let TypeScript know the module is an object. Updating the question with this new information. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the sub-module as individual modules.

In your typings (e.g. `typings/multi-mod-package.d.ts`):

```
declare module 'multi-mod-package/mod1' {
   // typings for mod1
}

declare module 'multi-mod-package/mod2' {
   // typings for mod2
}
```

For how to write your typings, you can check out the handbook:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

TypeScript does not do automatic deeplinking because node resolution for deep linking can be different than the typings structure.

Node deep linking is resolved based on the location of package.json.

Comment: When trying this, I kept running into an error when trying to do `import mod1 from "multi-mod-package/mod1";` (and `mod2`), but it turns out I needed to do `import * as mod1 from "multi-mod-package/mod1"` (and `mod2` again). Once I imported that way everything worked as expected. Marking this as correct.

Comment: Turn on `esModuleInterop`. It wil save you from so much troubles in the future.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea that existed. Thanks for the tip!